# C# Create employee. Save to SQL Database using EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm saving an employee to a SQL database. I'm saving Firstname, Lastname, Username and Password. How should I do this to prevent saving more than one identical username?

I've tried this:

```
    private void CreateEmployee()
    {
        using (var db = new TidrapportDBEntities())
        {
            var user = (from p
                       in db.Login
                        where p.username != null
                        select p).ToList();

            foreach (var vUser in user)
            {
                if (vUser.username == textBoxUsername.Text)
                {
                    labelSuccessFail.Visible = true;
                    labelSuccessFail.Text = "Accountname already exist.";

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    var userInfo = new Login();
                    var persInfo = new PersonalInformation();

                    persInfo.firstname = textBoxFirstname.Text;
                    persInfo.lastname = textBoxLastname.Text;

                    userInfo.username = textBoxUsername.Text;
                    userInfo.password = textBoxPassword.Text;
                    userInfo.employeeId = persInfo.employeeId;

                    db.Login.Add(userInfo);
                    db.PersonalInformation.Add(persInfo);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    textBoxFirstname.Text = string.Empty;
                    textBoxLastname.Text = string.Empty;
                    textBoxUsername.Text = string.Empty;
                    textBoxPassword.Text = string.Empty;

                    labelSuccessFail.Visible = true;
                    labelSuccessFail.Text = "Successfully created account.";
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

Any tips what I can try?

Kind regards,
Kristian

Comment: you should always check the name list saved in database before u save new name to prevent duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a unique constraint on the username field.  Not sure if you're doing code first, model first or DB first in your EF, but you should be able to google how to get it set on your database using the right method.   That will throw an exception if you try to save one, so that makes sure you can't have more than one.

You could also use LINQ statement to restrict the list of users to the user name you wish to create and then you're just down to checking a bool to see if a row is returned or not.  That way you're not having to read the entire database table (which your "toList" is doing).

In your code example, you're getting all the users where they have a user name, you're then looping round them, but your conditional code only really works if the first one matches the user name you're trying to save, otherwise you are going to try and recreate a duplicate the second time around.  So just to get your code working you could try:

```
   private void CreateEmployee()
    {
        using (var db = new TidrapportDBEntities())
        {
            var user = (from p
                       in db.Login
                        where p.username != null
                        select p).ToList();

            bool found = false;
            foreach (var vUser in user)
            {
                if (vUser.username == textBoxUsername.Text)
                {
                    found = true;
                    labelSuccessFail.Visible = true;
                    labelSuccessFail.Text = "Accountname already exist.";

                    break;
                }
           }

           if(!found)     
           {
                    var userInfo = new Login();
                    var persInfo = new PersonalInformation();

                    persInfo.firstname = textBoxFirstname.Text;
                    persInfo.lastname = textBoxLastname.Text;

                    userInfo.username = textBoxUsername.Text;
                    userInfo.password = textBoxPassword.Text;
                    userInfo.employeeId = persInfo.employeeId;

                    db.Login.Add(userInfo);
                    db.PersonalInformation.Add(persInfo);
                    db.SaveChanges();
```